# Grunt error "Grunt attempted to load a .coffee file but CoffeeScript was not installed."

Tags: javascript, npm, cmd, gruntjs

I am following [this tutorial](https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc) to test the AppRTC project that was created with WebRTC. Before starting the app server I need to run this command line "grunt build" to recompile the App Engine package.

When I run this command line `grunt build`  there are error messages displayed :

```
Loading "jinja.coffee" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Grunt attempted to load a .coffee file but CoffeeScript was not installed.
>> Please run `npm install --dev coffeescript` to enable loading CoffeeScript.

Running "shell:buildAppEnginePackage" (shell) task
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /mnt)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /mnt)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).

Running "shell:genJsEnums" (shell) task
src >>> src/web_app/js

Running "shell:copyAdapter" (shell) task

Running "shell:copyJsFiles" (shell) task

Done.
```

After I run this command line  `npm install --dev coffeescript` to install CoffeeScript but I get another error message

```
npm WARN install Usage of the `--dev` option is deprecated. Use `--include=dev` instead.
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  undefined
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

Later i tried to install CoffeeScript again with this command line `npm install --include=dev coffeescript` because the previous command line is obsolete. But I still get the error in my command line :

```
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  undefined
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-03-11T15_42_35_280Z-debug.log
```

I can't seem to see where problem is coming from, I have tried all three of these command line to fix this error, but it doesn't work.

Comment: What version of npm are you using? According to this, https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13935,  `npm i -f` should do the trick

Comment: Hello, I apologize for responding late, the version of npm I am using is 7.5.4

Comment: I run this command line `npm i -f ` and then after i run this command line again `npm install --include=dev coffeescript`  i still get the same errors.